# Visual Studio - not break on Java Exceptions in J#

Tags: java, visual-studio-2005, j#

I'm working on a project in J# that parses large amounts of data from a text file. Java doesn't have a good way of checking if a string is an integer, so I'm using parseInt inside a try-catch block.

I also have other try-catch blocks for file IO operations, etc. Sometimes I get CLR exceptions in other places where I'd like Visual Studio to break, even though the error is handled. To do this, I go into the Exceptions menu and check "Thrown". However, the Java exceptions apparently fall under CLR, but are not (ASAICT) specifically listed in that menu. So if I check Thrown for CLR, I get an error every single time an integer doesn't parse. This means I might have to hit continue 20-30 times to get past the parsing to the error I want to look at.

Is there any way to disable breaking on Java exceptions while still breaking on CLR exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used visual studio and there may be some way of doing this (- I know you can set breakpoints to only occur on specific types of exceptions in eclipse).

But you could avoid the checked exception entirely by using a regular expression to check to see if it's an int and then only parse it as an integer using Integer.valueOf() if it is.

Comment: You can set breakpoints to only occur on specific types of exceptions, but the Java exceptions aren't listed in the VS IDE. I'm not sure if it support regular expressions. I didn't want to use them but maybe I should try that.